# This is a Roman numeral to integer program, but the output is not what i was expecting

Tags: python

I expect `1994` as output, but i get `1014` when the input is `MCMXCIV`. Can you please give suggestions where my code went wrong. im a beginner to python, Thank you.

```
class Solution:
    def r2int(self,s):
        roman = {
            'I': 1,
            'V': 5,
            'X': 10,
            'L': 50,
            'C': 100,
            'D': 500,
            'M': 1000
        }
        s = s.replace('IV', 'IIII').replace('IX', 'V') #using replace function for exceptions
        s = s.replace('XL', 'XXX').replace('XC', 'V')
        s = s.replace('CD', 'V').replace('CM', 'V')
        integer = 0                                                #this is yet to become the final value
        for i in s:                                          #taking a character
            integer += roman[i]                                    #taking value from roman and adding to integer
        return integer                                             #final integer value
Solution().r2int('MCMXCIV')
```

Comment: Why are you replacing `CM` with `V`?

Comment: `CM` is 900, `V` is 5.

Comment: Thank you i wrote that for convenience but forgot to edit it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replace some of the Roman numerals wrong. For example, IX (which is 9) is not V (which is 5), XC (which is 90) is not V (5), etc. Replace:

```
s = s.replace('IV', 'IIII').replace('IX', 'V') #using replace function for exceptions
s = s.replace('XL', 'XXX').replace('XC', 'V')
s = s.replace('CD', 'V').replace('CM', 'V')
```

with

```
s = s.replace('IV', 'IIII').replace('IX', 'VIIII') #using replace function for exceptions
s = s.replace('XL', 'XXXX').replace('XC', 'LXXXX')
s = s.replace('CD', 'CCCC').replace('CM', 'DCCCC')
```

then the code works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler approach.  Let's map each numeral to its value.

```
roman = {
    'I': 1,
    'V': 5,
    'X': 10,
    'L': 50,
    'C': 100,
    'D': 500,
    'M': 1000
}

sample = 'MCMXCIV'

converted = [roman[digit] for digit in sample]
```

Now `converted` is `[1000, 100, 1000, 10, 100, 1, 5]`.

We could sum these, but that wouldn't account for things like `IV`. But if we negate any that are followed by a larger numeral, then we could sum them. We'll consider everything but the final digit.

```
for i in range(len(converted) - 1):
    if converted[i] < converted[i + 1]:
        converted[i] *= -1
```

Now `converted` is `[1000, -100, 1000, -10, 100, -1, 5]`.

And if we sum those numbers with `sum(converted)`, we get `1994`.

Comment: i dont really understand this method

Comment: When a smaller numeral appears before a larger numeral, it is subtracted from the total. That's how Roman numerals work. This method implements that by looking for that scenario. For instance, `'IV'` is initially mapped to `[1, 5]`, but because `1` is less that `5`, we change it to `-1`. Now if we sum those two numbers, we get `4`.